# Autosuggest input preventing text from being copied to other input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textbox, autosuggest

I am trying to have text copy from one text input field to the other as a user types.  I have been able to accomplish this thanks to everyone's help, but I ran into a problem.

If you visit the following page and type "Sub" in the "Car Manufacturer" text box, you will see it duplicate in the "TestField" text box.  However, since it is an autosuggest text box, Subaru pops up.

So, if you only type "Sub" and "Subaru" is suggested and you select it, only "Sub" is duplicated over to the next box.  You will notice also that once you select "Subaru" a checkbox is generated.  Maybe it would be better to duplicate from the checkbox instead?  But I have not been able to accomplish this unfortunately.

You can see the problem here (remember to only typ "sub" in the field and select "Subaru" to see what I'm talking about:

http://www.forzazone.com/forza-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/forza-motorsport-4-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/new-listing_c66/

Here is the code I'm currently using to perform the duplication:

```
<script>

(function($) {

   $('.jr-page').on('keyup','.jrAutoSuggest',function(){
      $('.jr_testfield').val($(this).val());
   });

})(jQuery);


</script>
```

If you have any ideas on how to prevent this that would be great.  One idea was to simply duplicate the text from the checkbox once "Subaru" is selected from the Autosuggest.

Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend the onclick method the  tag you are using for displaying the suggestions:

inside the tag:

```
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" onclick="javascript:clickHandler(this)">Subaru</a>
```

Implement the clickHandler function and set the value of the link to the test field you have created.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are referring to here since it has no <a> links... I think you are suggesting to apply onclick when I choose the selected text and then send it to the text field too?

Comment: The text 'Subaru' appears in the page as an <a> link. You can use the onClick event of the link to copy the value in the text field.